# RegEx in my htaccess doesn't work as intended

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

A few days ago my webhoster updated apache. Since then the error code 500 appears.
The problem is now, that apache seems to be more strict according to the htaccess syntax.
The error is fixed but my redirection doesn't work as intended.

The content of my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/DE/ [L,R=301]
```

Descripton:
I want to redirect www.domain.de and domain.de to http://www.domain.de/DE/.

Problem:

```
(www\.)
```

With this part the redirection doesnt work at all. If i delete it, it only works with domain.de but not www.domain.de.

Did i do any mistake in my htacces? I cant find any. I googled alot and found exactly this solution many times. Until now i spend a lot of hours on this problem but i dont make any progress.

Comment: You could opt to use two conditions instead: `RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain\.de$ [NC,OR]` `RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.domain\.de$ [NC]` (note the OR flag)

Comment: You shouldn't need to split out the conditions - it is simple enough to do with a regex as it is now. What might help is if we knew what "doesn't work at all" meant - does it not redirect? Does it throw an error? Is the code used exactly like what is shown (except with real domains)?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a case-sensitivity issue - the variable is actually `%{HTTP_HOST}`, not `%{http_host}` (see [RewriteCond docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond))

Also, I'm surprised that you don't get infinite redirect loops, since www.domain.de/DE/ will match both the RewriteCond and the RewriteRule.

Comment: You are right, it ends in a loop. Is the RewriteCond necessary in this case?

Comment: I do not understand why www.domain.de/DE/ matches my RewriteCond and RewriteRule? For me `www.domain.de/DE/` != `^(www.)domain.de$`.

Comment: Ok i found a solution. Tell my if im wrong but is RewriteRule/RewriteCond to redirect to other domains and RewriteMatch to redirect inside a domain? Now im using `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.domain.de/DE/` and so far it works like i want it to.

Comment: The docs give the details, but RewriteRule matches (and rewrites) paths, while RewriteCond puts a condition on a RewriteRule (which can be based on the path, the user agent, the domain, or more). www.domain.de/DE/ matches because "/DE/" matches the RewriteRule ("/DE/" is zero or more characters) and "www.domain.de" matches the RewriteCond (because it says "domain is www.domain.de or domain.de"), therefore it rewrites and puts itself into a loop.

Comment: If all you want is *just* www.domain.de and domain.de (without any path) to redirect to www.domain.de/DE/ then I'd recommend using mod_rewrite to force URLs *with* www. and then have an index.php file in the root that redirects users to /DE/. If that is what you want then I can update my answer.